# Is this drive compatible with PS3?

Tags: ps3

I am aware that 99% of HDDs that are 2.5" are compatible with the PS3 but before performing a purchase I would like to be 110% sure. I am looking into this HDD.

**Western Digital Blue Portable WD7500BPVX**

Is it compatible? Is there any other feature to check besides that it being 2.5" Sata hdd?

Comment: If it's a 2.5" SATA drive, there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the customer reviews on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C9TEC0Y) they work very well. For example:

> My husband bought this HDD for his PS3 Slim. It fits perfect and worked like a charm. He is happy as can be.

And another one:

> Bought this hard drive to upgrade a PS3 with and everything went perfectly. Did a lot of research first and saw some pretty unfounded statements about hard drive limits on the PS3. I opted to go the route of backing up save games only (don't forget to do this separately for all users on the PS3), so the total time to swap drives was all of 5 minutes. Plus maybe another 10-15 to update firmware package and format.